# Options on how to Update a table with millions of records

Tags: teradata

I have a situation where one of the table has a new column go added. I have to update this table by joining another table to populate this new column.

I am trying to use the below but i am not sure how would be performance for this.

```
UPDATE A  
FROM MPTR.ACCS_METH_EVENT A, 
(
SELECT EVENT_ID,DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_CD FROM 
MPTR.EVENT
WHERE DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_CD IS NOT NULL
AND EVENT_START_DT<DATE+1
GROUP BY 1,2 
) B
SET  DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_CD=B.DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_CD
WHERE A.EVENT_ID=B.EVENT_ID
AND A.DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_CD IS NULL ;
```

The event table has partition created on event_start_dt.

What is the best approach in this scenario??

I tried something like that but its is failing as the TDWM filter violation error is coming. I have used the partitioned column here but still getting the error.

```
MERGE MPTR.ACCS_METH_EVENT as Target1
USING MPTR.EVENT  as source1
ON Target1.EVENT_ID = source1.EVENT_ID   and source1.event_start_dt< date
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN   
 UPDATE SET DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_CD=source1.DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_CD
```

Comment: The table has 2,427,747,900 many records.

Comment: Just curious, WHAT table can have over 2 billion records?

Comment: Mobile numbers, payments tables, network related CDRS tables etc.

Comment: Of course there are huge tables, but which table in your update has 2 billion rows, source or target? Btw, you might have multiple rows per EVENT_ID, resulting in an error, *target row updated by multiple source rows*.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth Both the table the source and the target are huge. 
Yes i  will check for target row error.
What approach should i follow?

Comment: I have used a group by to avoid target row updated error

Comment: @dnoeth Can i convert this to a merge statement?

Comment: @user3901666: For the Merge you should calculate the source data in a Derived Table, e.g `SELECT EVENT_ID,MAX(DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_CD)` (this would also avoid the *target row* error), but the PI of the target table must be `EVENT_ID`, otherwise Merge is not possible.

Comment: And speed-wise, 2B record update on TD14/TD15 was not a big deal. But you can always batch it, breaking by year, for instance, one update at a time.

Comment: @dnoeth, What should i go for then merge or simple update?
I am able to execute the merge statement for sample data for 2 tables.However, for one table the event_id is defined as SI and not PI. Can i do merge on that?

Comment: @user3901666: Use a few percent sample tables and test both approaches. DBQL data will show which one needs less resources, probably the Merge.